# Expression link to report while passing parameter

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I have a report that contains an order number. I want this order number text to be clickable, passing the value as a parameter to another report. My current report is set up to group on Item, then Component, and list the orders those are included in. 
[image]

The order # column is populated with the following expression.

```
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!Component.Value, Fields!Component.Value, Trim(Fields!Order_Number.Value), "DataSet1") , ", ")
```

Adding an action to the text box or placeholder properties doesn't pass the correct value.

Is there a way to make those individual order numbers clickable to run a separate report, while passing the order numbers as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeeeeeess but it's probably going to be irritating. I've never done it myself but it should be possible.

What you can do is, instead of returning `Trim(Fields!Order_Number.Value)` via your `LookUpSet()`, actually return an `<a href=...` HTML link to the drill down report, then right click the TEXT in the Order # Textbox (I.E. the `<<Expr>>` rather than the Textbox itself), go to Placeholder Properties and then change "Markup Type" to "HTML - Interpret HTML tags as styles". You should craft the URL to point at the report you want to run and include the Order number as a Parameter - this will make each individual Order number clickable.

A little messy but it ought to work fine.

For more info on running reports with Parameters in the URL, see [this msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155391.aspx)

Comment: I tested your answer and it worked, though I found an easier way using an extremely simple subreport.